# Save XML data into database as columns in C#

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm writing an C# application that watch for newly created xml files, and I want to insert some of the data in these XML files to a SQL database. One file is one row in the database.

What is the best and easiest way to do this?

What I have done so far is to defined a DataTable with the columns I want from the XML. After that I use ReadXML on the DataSet. This give me a DataSet with one table and one row, and the columns I want. So far it's perfect. But I can't find a good way to ONLY insert this new DataRow into my MSSQL database. I don't have any unique ID for that row yet. Would this make it easier? I don't want to map my dataset with the database, I'm only doing an insert...

Comment: [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) -> [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) -> [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) as a start. Then `"INSERT INTO [Table] ([Field1], [Field2] ...) VALUES (@Field1Value, @Field2Value ...)"`. Set the parameter values and `ExecuteNonQuery` the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: if you don't have unique ID that is not problem as far as inserting data, but you might not be able to set unique column later.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the ID:

```
    string query = "INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeID, Name, Phone) "+
                   "OUTPUT INSERTED.EmployeeID "+
                   "VALUES (NEWID(), 'John Kris', '99-99999')";
    Guid lastId = (Guid)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

The rest of the things you do sound ok for me.

Comment: So you're saying that I can't save my DataTable directly into the database without creating my Insert statement from scratch?

Comment: As for my knowledge you will allways have to somehow map the values from one datasource (xml) to the other (db). Be it in code or your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

I used LINQ to SQL to solve this. I set it up somewhat like described here:
[LINQ to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11295371/1049723). 
On the data context I used [InsertOnSubmit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx).